# Getting TestCafe to recognize dotenv variables

Tags: automated-tests, e2e-testing, vue-cli, testcafe, dotenv

I might be mixing up concepts, but [I'd read that it's possible to get TestCafe to recognize variables](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/access-environment-variables-in-tests.html) of the form `process.env.MY_COOL_VARIABLE`. Also for my Vue.js frontend (built using Vue-CLI, [which uses dotenv under the hood](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes)), I found I could make a file in `.env.test` for test values like so:

```
VUE_APP_MY_COOL_VARIABLE
```

which I would then access in my test code like so:

```
test('my fixture', async (t) => {
 ...
 await t
      .click(mySelector.find('.div').withText(process.env.VUE_APP_MY_COOL_VARIABLE));
 ...

}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
"text" argument is expected to be a string or a regular expression, but it was undefined.
```

Seems like my environment variables aren't getting picked up. I build my code like so: `vue-cli-service build --mode test`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I solved my issue. When debugging, I did a `console.log` of `process.env` and noticed that the variable that vue recognizes wasn't visible during testcafe's run. From our package.json:

```
"test:ui:run": "VUE_APP_MY_COOL_VARIABLE=ui-test yarn build:test && testcafe -a ../ui-test-server.sh chrome",
```

Also this bit of javascript is run by both the test and mainline code, so I had to use a conditional.

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

if (process.env.npm_package_scripts_test_ui_run) { // are we running a testcafe script
  dotenv.config({ path: '.env.test' });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

TestCafe doesn't provide support for `.env` files out of the box. You can create a test file that will require the `dotenv` module and load your configuration file:

```js
// enable-dotenv.test.js
require('dotenv').config({ path: '.my.env' });
```

```
testcafe chrome enable-dotenv.test.js tests/
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried process.env[VUE_APP_MY_COOL_VARIABLE]? It's worth noting that everything in dotenv comes back as a string so you may need to do the casting yourself. For example:

```
function getEnvVariableValue(envVariable: string) {
    // Cast to boolean
    if (envVariableValue.toUpperCase() === "TRUE") {
        return true;
    } else if (envVariableValue.toUpperCase() === "FALSE") {
        return false;
        // Cast to number
    } else if (!isNaN(Number(envVariableValue))) {
        return Number(envVariableValue);
    } else {
        return envVariableValue;
    }
}
```

You can also try creating a .env file in the root folder to see if it picks it that way. I use dotenv in my project directly by including it in the package.json as a dependency and it works this way.

Comment: I'm only including strings in my variables. I've tried adding dotenv to package.json but that didn't seem to take.

Comment: Here's what mine looks like:

"dependencies": {
    "@types/dotenv": "^6.1.1",
    "@types/node": "^11.11.3",
    "dotenv": "^8.0.0"
  }
I've tested it by both adding to the .env file and setting the environment directly.

Comment: Okay, but I'm not using .env, I am using .env.test because it's important to have these values only injected in my test environment.

Comment: By default dotenv looks for a .env file, if you need to change that you'll need to specify the file directly:
dotenv.config({ path: envFile })

Comment: It's worth noting that dotenv discourages the pattern of having a separate test files though: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#should-i-have-multiple-env-files

Comment: I noticed that, but it’s a decision made and supported by the vue-cli team.